# How can I get the values in the header of a request in the class that contains web services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, header

I have a class which contains some methods (web services of the web api). I could get the header values of requests in the body of methods this way:

```
var re = Request;
var headers = re.Headers;
string token = string.Empty;
StringValues x = default(StringValues);
if (headers.ContainsKey("Custom"))
{
   var m = headers.TryGetValue("Custom", out x);
}
```

But what i need is to set the value of two static variables(called domainName and workSpaceName) based on the header values(the values are included in the body of all requests) not in the body of methods also in the body of class. something like this:

```
public class Controller : ....
{
        static string domain = "";
        static string workSpace = "";
}
```

var re = Request; is not valid in the body of class. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. just add this in the class:

```
static string domain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Domain"];
```